# XML query not always pulling up results?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've been playing around with XML a little, trying to learn how it works, and ran into an odd problem. Sometimes, when I query my XML file, I don't get results that I know exist. In fact, the only one I do get results for is the very first entry. The following is some example XML entries and a small function to see if a user exists.

```
<users>
  <user>
    <username>a</username>
    <firstname>a</firstname>
    <lastname>a</lastname>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>b</username>
    <firstname>b</firstname>
    <lastname>b</lastname>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>rawr</username>
    <firstname>a</firstname>
    <lastname>a</lastname>
  </user>
</users>
```

>

```
private bool FindUser(string username)
{
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);


        var data = from item in doc.Descendants("users")
                   where item.Element("user").Element("username").Value == username.ToLower()
                   select new
                   {
                       usernameEle = item.Element("user").Element("username").Value
                   };

        var p = data.FirstOrDefault();
        if (p != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

If I try to search for the user "a", it returns true. If I do a search for any other username, it returns false.

I'm sure there is a simple solution but it is eluding me! Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the value of p where you have `var p = data.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: When I try search the username "a", p comes back with 'usernameEle = "a"'. When I search any other username, it is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer... but I'm not sure WHY this worked. I'm still somewhat new to XML...

I changed "item.Element("user").Element("username").Value" to "item.Element("username").Value". Also changed "from item in doc.Descendants("users")" to "from item in doc.Descendants("user")"

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("users")
           where item.Element("user").Element("username").Value == username.ToLower()
           select new
           {
               usernameEle = item.Element("user").Element("username").Value
           };
```

to

```
var data = from item in doc.Descendants("user")
           where item.Element("username").Value == username.ToLower()
           select new
           {
               usernameEle = item.Element("username").Value
           };
```

It is now able to retrieve more than just the first entry. If I search b, or rawr, I get the appropriate results.

Odd.

Comment: Notice that you're now searching for descendants of "user" also.. which puts you in the `<user>` tag.

Comment: Ah yea, I should have pointed out that I changed that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is just looking at the first `user` element.  You want to change it to look at all users.  An any easy way to do it is just get all "user" elements and then test the username value as you have answer.

A shorter implementation would be:

```
bool IsUserPresent(string username)
{
    username = username.ToLower();
    var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    return doc
      .Descendants("user")
      .Any(u => u.Element("username").Value == username));
}
```

Comment: If you like the answer, then please accept it.  Accepting answers gets more people to answer your new questions.